# Need to Know about query execution plan

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

Is there any way to view the mysql/oracle query execution plan as like java debugging.
i want to know how mysql/oracle executes our query and what are the steps involved in execution.

Comment: For MySQL, you want `EXPLAIN`. No idea with Oracle.

Comment: Ah, there we go: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: Thank u,
but i've read that explain will show an approximation only, and not the exact query execution plan.

Comment: That's the closest you're going to get without recompiling the DBMS with all sorts of debug printouts jammed in there (which you can't do with Oracle anyway).

Answer (score 6):

For mysql you should use

```
EXPLAIN <query>
```

e.g.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tableX
```

see [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/explain.html)

For oracle there is something similar but more detailed:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <query>
```

e.g.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM tableX
```

see also: [reference for oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm)

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL you want `EXPLAIN`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

And on Oracle, it's `EXPLAIN PLAN`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm